# Exclude template function from C++ Builder headers generated from Delphi source classes

Tags: templates, delphi, generics, c++builder

I have a library that is using Generic methods in Delphi classes. Such as

```
function CreateInstance<T: TMyInstance>(const Name: string): T; overload;
```

There will be a lot of different instance types that derive from TMyInstance.

It seems that the compiler properly generates headers for C++Builder as follows:

```
template<typename T> T __fastcall CreateInstance(const System::UnicodeString Name)/* overload */;
```

but it does not seem to work in practice, except for a few types that I have created alias functions in the library too.

So, all in all, I decided to add another option for instantiating the different types that works also in C++. But I would still like to keep the Generic functions in Delphi.

Is there any way to disable the generation of these function templates, so that the C++ Builder users of the library would not even see them - since they will not work for them, anyways?

I tried [{$NODEFINE}](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/NODEFINE_directive_(Delphi)), but it seems to exclude complete types only and not individual functions.

I can imagine that I can remove the generated lines from the hpp-files after the build with a script, but it feels a bit kludgy.

Comment: Kludgy or not, it is the only way. There is no directive in the Delphi compiler for the level of control you want.

Comment: Tx @RemyLebeau, that's what I was afraid of. Well, I think I already have an old fixhpp batch file that I can amend for these :)